# Echo of Option Menu Shows as "%"

Tags: php

I have an option menu with several options including show all records. The option menu is fed by a query on a MySQL table. I am trying to echo the option selected and everything works until I select all records. Then the echo shows as %. Would like for it to echo ALL when All records is selected from option menu. I am using the following to echo:

```
    <?PHP echo isset($_POST['selGrade']) ? $_POST['selGrade'] : 'ALL'; ?>
```

Currently the default option is all records, which echos ALL correctly with my PHP statement above. Problem happens when I select another option and then select all records again. Then it echos "%". What can I add to the PHP statement to echo ALL when a user selects All records?

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup of the form?

Comment: I have posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Peter Darmis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2560539/peter-darmis), the solution to my question is:

```
<?PHP 
    if(!isset($_POST['selGrade']) || empty($_POST['selGrade']) || 
$_POST['selGrade']=="%"){
$text = "ALL";
} else {
$text = $_POST['selGrade'];
}
echo $text;
     ?>
```

I asked a similar question at [Option Menu Showing Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064628/option-menu-showing-undefined-index?noredirect=1#comment61675635_37064628). Thanks to all.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing "all records" empties the `$_POST['selGrade']` but doesn't unset it. Consider using `!empty($_POST['selGrade'])` instead of `isset()`.

[Function empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: D14n4, I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it still echos %. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've added my solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your form, but if you prefer to ignore it suit yourself :)