# Option Menu Showing Undefined Index

Tags: php, mysql

Have an option menu that is driving me crazy.

```
<?PHP 
$text=($_POST['selGrade']);
echo (!empty($text) ? $text : "ALL");
?>
```

The menu is fed by a table that is set to % to show all records on page load. On load the page shows "Notice: Undefined index: selGrade in..."
Selecting an option will echo correctly. Selecting All records from the option Menu will echo "%".

Here is my option menu:

```
<form id="formGrade" name="formGrade" method="post" action="#Grade">
  Filter  by grade level: <strong>
  <select name="selGrade" id="selGrade"  
  onchange="formGrade.submit()">
  <option value="%">all grade levels</option>
  <?php
  do {  
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetGrade['Grade']?>"<?php

    if ($varGrade_Recordset15 == $row_RecordsetGrade['Grade']) {echo 'selected';} ?>>
    <?php echo $row_RecordsetGrade['Grade']?></option>
    <?php
  } while ($row_RecordsetGrade = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetGrade));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetGrade);
  if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($RecordsetGrade, 0);
    $row_RecordsetGrade = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetGrade);
  }
  ?>
</select>
</strong><a href="course_types.php">reset</a>
</form>
```

I just want it to echo the option menu selected. All grades (which is the default should echo "ALL" and everything else seems to be working fine. Problem seems to be the onload and when selecting All Records again. Any suggestions?

Comment: start with `if (isset($_POST['selGrade']))`

Comment: You already posted answer to your question. Why you are asking again it? If it is not solved open same question again. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37008232/2156244

Comment: Why you have used option value as `%` ,  `<option value="%">all grade levels</option>`, **change it to some variable or a value**

Comment: Trying to show all records initially. Use % to show all.

Comment: Apb-Thought I had solved. Reset the page and problem returned.

Comment: On reset page `POST` value is not set. Please check @Peter Darmis's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change in your code

```
 if(!isset($_POST['selGrade']) || empty($_POST['selGrade']) || $_POST['selGrade']=="%"){
    $text = "ALL";
    } else {
    $text = $_POST['selGrade'];
    }
    echo $text;
```

Comment: Changing to zero had no effect. Still getting undefined.

Comment: i think i did not understand your question in the beginning try the edited answer.

Comment: I was getting an error on your code above so I added a semicolon after "ALL". Not I get no error messages but it is not echoing anything. Blank.

Comment: Yes you are right for the semicolon i corrected it. Still not echoing `$text` correctly?

Comment: OK. Now it loads fine. It also goes to other options successfully. Only problem is that if I return to all records from another menu choice, it echoes "%". FYI I still have <option value="%"> on form.

Comment: I've always used % for option value when I am showing all records. Using option value="0" as suggested by another user resulted in an error "Warning: Division by zero in..."

Comment: I never want the echo to show %. I would like for it to show All records or other menu choice.

Comment: You are a Godsend. I have wasted too many hours on this. Success. Many thanks. You are awesome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111180/discussion-between-peter-darmis-and-user3258571).